# Internet Bookmarks

Tags: synchronization, bookmarks, firefox, trello-organization

In Firefox I have on the order of 10^3 bookmarks. I need a tool which provides the following features:

- Grouping (tagging / categorization - either is acceptable)
- Browser (prefer Firefox) integration (can use standard tools to cross browsers/systems)
- No vendor lock-in (can export my data in standard formats)

These all come standard, though grouping is buggy, in Firefox. I would like:

- Automatic offline archival of website content (ie, text of blog post)
- Social shareability is a plus
- FOSS is a plus, as is free-as-in-beer
- personal knowledge base integration is nice

Have considered:

- Fx bookmarks (buggy, most likes short)
- Write myself (effort duplication?, buggy, incomplete, more interesting problems)

  - social bookmarks backend (ie, digg, delicious, etc)
- Tiddywiki (+is current knowledge base, -not integrate with web browser)

Of those three, the second is the only one that effectively meets my core requirements, while still possibly meeting some of the wants. However, a theoretical panacea is valued far below a practical cure.

What applications/tools have I overlooked that best meet these challenges? I am not adverse to a little cash, or a little scripting, to make it work.

Migrated from: https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/826/internet-bookmarks.

Comment: I eventually have gone with http://pinboard.in, and I am quite happy with the service - it is approximately what I would have spent my time to build (MUCH more polished though), and the one time fee is acceptable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/), which may have everything you are after,though I am not sure they offer is the offline archiving, but you could probably do that with another application.  Otherwise, it's got the social shareablity, grouping, integration (I know of at least 2 plugins for Chrome, so I imagine they have more than that for FF.

It's also backed by [correction: AVOS, see below], which gives it some stability over the long haul.  I can't remember what their plans are for it, but as far as I know they are keeping it around.

[XMarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) is a good option if you don't want the social aspects of Delicious, and it provides more of a hierarchical organization rather than a tag-based one.

Both of these solutions work across all major browsers, so you can have access to the same bookmarks in a different browser on the same machine, or wherever you are.

Comment: Delicious is no longer Yahoo, it's been bought by [AVOS](http://www.avos.com/) as of April 27, 2011.

Comment: I'm going to give Delicious a shot; I admit that it seems to have changed somewhat since I last tried it in April 2009. In particular, there is the ability to export bookmarks. If the browser integrations works well, the large ecosystem surrounding a popular service might provide the knowledgebase or offline archival aspects. Going to accept, pending an honest failed trial of the service.

Comment: @michaelc Yes, the only thing you can do is try it out.  Good luck.

Comment: Browser integration hasn't impressed me very much. Might use it as a back end, but their interface isn't wonderful.

Comment: @michaelc Did you use their plugin?  There are lots of other great ones.  I use Chromicious.  Make sure you set it up so it intercepts the ctrl+D (to set a bookmark) automatically (you end up with a local copy, too).

Comment: @jonsca The pinboard.in plugin is admittedly much closer to what I would call ideal.

Comment: @michaelc I had looked into it at one time myself, I've settled in with the new Delicious, but I'm going to be overhauling my bookmarks soon.  Hope it works out for the best!

Answer (score 1):

[SemanticScuttle](http://semanticscuttle.sourceforge.net) is an Open Source self-hosted bookmark application you could use.

Browser integration is possible by a bookmarklet to easily add new bookmarks, and opensearch integration to find bookmarks from your search bar. But it could be much better, there is no deep browser integration.

It provides bookmark export in standard formats.

Offline archiving is [planned](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3296686&group_id=211356&atid=1017433), but not implemented.

"Social shareability" - it supports multiple user accounts and you can share protected bookmarks with your watchlist, but federation (automatic sharing across servers) is not implemented, but [planned](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3093826&group_id=211356&atid=1017433).